# Adding miscellaneous files to autotools

Tags: build-automation, automake

I have a data files of precalculated data, which should be included in my project under `test` subdirectory, so that test unit can read them and compare calculated results with what they're supposed to be. Doing `make dist` there are not included in the final tarball. How do I tell automake to include them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use EXTRA_DIST.  See the "Basics of Distribution" section in the manual.